# snap: cannot abort change 18 with nothing pending

Tags: snap

somehow snap crashed.

```
ID   Status  Spawn                    Ready                    Summary
17   Done    yesterday at 23:03 CEST  yesterday at 23:03 CEST  Auto-refresh snap "core"
18   Done    today at 11:35 CEST      today at 11:35 CEST      Auto-refresh snap "snapd"
19   Done    today at 12:07 CEST      today at 12:07 CEST      Remove "skype" snap
20   Done    today at 12:09 CEST      today at 12:09 CEST      Install "skype" snap from "latest/stable" channel
21   Done    today at 12:16 CEST      today at 12:16 CEST      Remove "skype" snap
22   Done    today at 12:24 CEST      today at 12:24 CEST      Install "skype" snap from "latest/stable" channel
```

I have this pending operation and I cannot abort them

```
thomas@XPS:~$ sudo snap abort 17
error: cannot abort change 18 with nothing pending
```

Any ideas?